# Replace all the text in a div with class name - only js

Tags: javascript, class, innerhtml

I'm trying to all the text in a div by class name:

```
<div class="something...">
```

And then replace the text with something. No, i don't want to use jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be straight forward

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.something');

for ( var i=elements.length; i--; ) {
    elements[i].textContent = "something else";
}
```

```html
<div class="something">Soft</div>
<br>
<div class="something">Kitty</div>
<br>
<div class="something">Warm</div>
<br>
<div class="something">Kitty</div>
<br>
<span class="something" style="color:green">Little ball of fur ...</span>
```